# Is there a Windows 10 privacy checklist?

Tags: windows-10, privacy, windows-10-v1607

I would like to know what settings should be changed on a new Windows 10 (Pro, but a canonical answer covering all editions would be nice) installation to disable as much of the built-in telemetry/tracking as possible.

I am looking for both GUI-solutions as well as GPO/Registry modifications.

The duplicate doesn't answer my question as I'm also looking for hidden settings only accessible via GPO/registry, like for example disabling the start menu's web search (impossible via the normal GUI after the anniversary update).

Regards.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: @DavidPostill not a duplicate, I'm also looking for GPO/registry settings which the duplicate doesn't talk about.

Comment: @AndréBorie , we are always glad to help, but at the time that David posted his comment it was an accurate assessment.  You edited your question several hours afterwards, and adding a requirement where you are also seeking GPO/registry modifications changes the scope of the question to a large degree.  Originally, both David's comment and my answer were well within the constraints of what you wanted.  That being said, I updated my answer with information from one of my favorite IT web sites that is applicable to Windows 10 group policy privacy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best article I have seen in that regard comes from Paul Thurrott:

[Windows 10 Tip: Understand and Configure Privacy Settings](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5337/windows-10-tip-understand-and-configure-privacy-settings)

Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then select **Privacy**

[image: Privacy Settings]

> **Privacy, General**
>
> In Privacy, General, you will see options for disabling the personal advertising ID (which will result in non-personalized ads), disabling the SmartScreen filter on Store apps (which would be dumb), disabling the anonymous sending typing and writing data to Microsoft in order to improve Windows (which would be selfish), and disabling the ability of browsers to understand your configured language(s) for purposes of providing local content (and, I presume, language-correct advertising). There is also a link to the Microsoft Privacy web site, where you can learn more and configure these settings globally for your Microsoft account and/or the current web browser.
>
> **Privacy, Location**
>
> Here, you can configure and learn about your location settings. Key among the capabilities here is an app list so you can enable location globally but prevent certain apps from accessing this information if you’d like.
>
> **Privacy, Camera**
>
> As you might expect, this interface lets you globally enable or disable the camera(s) in your PC and determine which apps can access the camera(s).
>
> **Privacy, Microphone**
>
> Ditto, but for the microphone.
>
> **Privacy, Speech, ink and typing**. Cortana—which you must explicitly opt into and then later explicitly opt into voice control—will learn your writing (via keyboard or pen) and voice over time so that she can more accurately respond to your questions. Likewise, Cortana—which, remember, is a digital personal assistant—must have access to your calendar and contacts, and collection information about you in her notebook, in order to work at all. If you don’t like that, turn it all off. And don’t use Cortana.
>
> **Privacy, Account info**. Some Windows Store apps—I couldn’t find any on the three PCs and one tablet I’m using on this trip—will use your account name, picture, and other info to personalize your experience. You can turn this ability off globally or on an app-by-app basis.
>
> **Privacy, Contacts**. You can explicitly configure which apps have access to your contacts list.
>
> **Privacy, Calendar**. Ditto, but for your schedule. You can also globally disable calendar access.
>
> **Privacy, Messaging**. You can globally enable or disable the ability of apps to read or send text messages (SMS and MMS). You can also choose which apps have this access.
>
> **Privacy, Radio**. Some radios in your PC or tablet—like Bluetooth—can be controlled by apps. You can disable this functionality globally or on an app-by-app basis.
>
> **Privacy, Other devices**. Devices you have explicitly paired with your PC or tablet—like a smart phone—can automatically sync data and share information. You can disable this functionality globally or on an app-by-app basis.
>
> **Privacy, Feedback and diagnostics**. By default, Windows will automatically ask you for feedback from time to time, and if you don’t like that, you can change the timing or just turn it off. Likewise, you can configure how or whether anonymous diagnostic information is sent to Microsoft so they can make Windows better. (If you are a member of the Windows Insider program and have enabled Insider access on the current PC, you cannot change this setting, and automatic diagnostic information collection is required.)
>
> **Privacy, Background apps**. While this is more of a battery life issue than a privacy issue, Windows lets you configure which apps are allowed to run in the background. These apps can stay up to date by receiving information from the Internet, and can trigger notifications … even when you’re not using them. The horrors.

On the other hand, if you are trying to configure privacy settings on a Windows 10 Professional machine for all users by utilizing the Group Policy editor (**gpedit.msc**), you have numerous options at your disposal:

> **Location on/off**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Locations and Sensors
>
> If you enable this policy setting, the location feature is turned off, and all programs on this computer are prevented from using location information from the location feature.
>
> **Allow input personalization**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options
>
> Automatic learning enables the collection of speech and handwriting patterns, typing history, contacts, and recent calendar information. It is required for the use of Cortana.  Some of this collected information may be stored on the user's OneDrive, in the case of inking and typing; some of the information will be uploaded to Microsoft to personalize speech.
>
> **User management of sharing user name account picture and domain information with apps (not desktop apps)**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > User Profiles
>
> This setting prevents users from managing the ability to allow apps to access the user name, account picture, and domain information.
>
> **Access contacts**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Privacy > Let Windows apps access contacts
>
> **Access calendar**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Privacy > Let Windows apps access the calendar
>
> **Read or send messages**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Privacy > Let Windows apps access messaging
>
> **Disable Radios**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Privacy > Let Windows apps control radios
>
> **Sync info with wireless devices**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Privacy > Let Windows apps access trusted devices
>
> **Feedback frequency**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview Builds > Do not show feedback notifications
>
> **Allow Telemetry**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview builds
>
> This policy setting determines the amount of diagnostic and usage data reported to Microsoft. A value of 0 indicates that no telemetry data from OS components is sent to Microsoft.
>
> **Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > OneDrive
>
> This policy setting lets you prevent apps and features from working with files on OneDrive.
>
> **Allow indexing of encrypted files**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search
>
> If you enable this policy setting, indexing will attempt to decrypt and index the content (access restrictions will still apply).
>
> **Allow search and Cortana to use location**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search
>
> If this is enabled, search and Cortana can access location information.
>
> **Do not allow web search**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search
>
> Enabling this policy removes the option of searching the Web from Windows Desktop Search.
>
> **Don't search the web or display web results in Search**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search
>
> If you don't configure this policy setting, a user can choose whether or not Search can perform queries on the web over metered connections, and if the web results are displayed in Search.
>
> **Set what information is shared in Search**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search
>
> This policy setting allows you to control what information is shared with Bing in Search.
>
> **Sync Your Settings (various policies)**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components
>
> Prevent syncing to and from this PC.  This turns off and disables the "sync your settings" switch on the "sync your settings" page in PC Settings.
>
> **Disable Windows Error Reporting (various policies)**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting
>
> This policy setting turns off Windows Error Reporting, so that reports are not collected or sent to either Microsoft or internal servers within your organization when software unexpectedly stops working or fails.
>
> **Join Microsoft MAPS**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender > MAPS
>
> Microsoft MAPS is the online community that helps you choose how to respond to potential threats. You can choose to send basic or additional information about detected software. This information can include things like location of detected items on your computer if harmful software was removed. The information will be automatically collected and sent.
>
> **Sent file samples when further analysis is required**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender > MAPS
>
> This policy setting configures behavior of samples submission when opt-in for MAPS telemetry is set.
>
> **Do not send a Windows error report when a generic driver is installed on a device**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation
>
> Windows has a feature that sends "generic-driver-installed" reports through the Windows Error Reporting infrastructure.
>
> **Turn off Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Internet Communication Management > Internet Communication settings
>
> The Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program collects information about your hardware configuration and how you use our software and services to identify trends and usage patterns.
>
> **Turn off Windows Error Reporting**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Internet Communication Management > Internet Communication settings
>
> Error Reporting is used to report information about a system or application that has failed or has stopped responding and is used to improve the quality of the product.
>
> **Turn off Application Telemetry**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Application Compatibility
>
> Application Telemetry is a mechanism that tracks anonymous usage of specific Windows system components by applications.
>
> **Turn off Inventory Collector**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Application Compatibility
>
> The Inventory Collector inventories applications, files, devices, and drivers on the system and sends the information to Microsoft. This information is used to help diagnose compatibility problems.
>
> **Prevent participation in the Customer Experience Improvement Program**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer
>
> This policy setting prevents the user from participating in the Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP).
>
> **Prevent Windows Media DRM Internet Access**
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Media Digital Rights Management
>
> When enabled, Windows Media DRM is prevented from accessing the Internet (or intranet) for license acquisition and security upgrades.­
>
> **Prevent Music File Media Information Retrieval**
>
> User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Media Player
>
> This policy setting allows you to prevent media information for music files from being retrieved from the Internet.
>
> **Prevent Music CD and DVD Media Information Retrieval**
>
> User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Media Player
>
> This policy setting allows you to prevent media information for CDs and DVDs from being retrieved from the Internet.

([Source](https://4sysops.com/wiki/windows-10-privacy-settings/))

Comment: This does not talk about the settings you can apply using GPO and/or by editing the registry.

Comment: No, it doesn't... but your original question didn't specify that you were looking for that level of detail (with potential group policy and/or registry modifications).  Based upon what you said, Paul's article provides a rather thorough description of how *"to disable as much of the built-in telemetry/tracking as possible."*